# Google Proxy IP's in my company website access log from company user

Tags: google, proxy, logs

For whatever strange reason, a user within my company has requests proxied through google proxy servers to our company website.. Instead of her requests coming from office ip to our website, its coming from one of these or more ip's google-proxy-66.249.93.85..

she is the only one affected and it started recently.. we have reloaded her chrome with a brand new install and a brand new profile and the issue still exists and also only within chrome.. i am aware of the google data saver chrome extension, but this is not installed either..

Running Windows 10 and the issue only exists in chrome no other browser..

any advice would be helpful..

Comment: "we have reloaded her chrome" - Is this Chrome on (Windows?) Desktop on a work PC? Is this user "signed in" to Chrome? "only within chrome.." - just to clarify, other browsers (Firefox, IE, etc.) do not show these symptoms?

Comment: @zaslayer / duanne - You seem to have logged in as a different user? This will make editing and responding to comments rather difficult. (?)